# Google Map Screenshot black

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.forms

I want to take google map screenshot in my xamarin PCL Project. The map is displaying perfectly. But when i try to take screenshot it is displaying black screen of the google map part.

[image: Map is displaying on screen like below]

But when i try to take by code screenshot is displaying like below.
[image: Screenshot via code]

```
public interface IScreenshotService
{
   Task<byte[]> Capture();
}


public class ScreenshotService : IScreenshotService
{
    public static Activity Activity { get; set; }

    //public void SetActivity(Activity activity) => _currentActivity = activity 

    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<byte[]> Capture()
    {
        if (Activity == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("You have to set ScreenshotManager.Activity in your Android project");
        }

        var view = Activity.Window.DecorView;
        view.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = view.GetDrawingCache(true);

        byte[] bitmapData;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
            bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
        }

        return bitmapData;
    }
}
```

Code to for calling function

```
byte[] screenshotData = await DependencyService.Get<IScreenshotService>().Capture();
```

can you help me to figure out the issue?

Comment: Try : Call this `view.BuildDrawingCache();` after `GetDrawingCache` and then put some delay before capturing screen.

Comment: @GaurangDave  is this will be find  Bitmap bitmap = view.GetDrawingCache(true);
            view.BuildDrawingCache();
            await Task.Delay(1000);

Comment: `view.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;view.BuildDrawingCache(); await Task.Delay(1000); Bitmap bitmap = view.GetDrawingCache(true);` I suggest this but I would request you to try these statement in different sequence as I can not code it right now.

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be **Images of the map must not be transmitted to your servers, or otherwise used outside of the application**
and you could use `GoogleMap.snapshot` method to take snapshots of the map

simply implement the following interface: [onSnapshotReady](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback)

```
public abstract void onSnapshotReady (Bitmap snapshot)
```

and call:[snapshot](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#snapshot(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback))

```
public final void snapshot (GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback)
```

you alse could refer to the example (in jave) :[screenshot answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773658/capture-screen-shot-of-googlemap-android-api-v2/18093295#18093295)

Comment: thanks for your comments but i want to do this in Xamarin Forms Application

Comment: i know .i mean you use DependencyService to call the ScreenshotService ,then you could write the code in Droid (only conversion from java to C# ,refer to the document and link)

Answer (score 0):

This might be because what you are doing is against the Terms of Service of Google Maps Platform, according to the article:

> 3.2.4a "No Scraping.  Customer will not extract, export, scrape, or cache Google Maps Content for use outside the Services."

You may visit [Google Maps Platform Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3-license) to learn more about Licensing.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i can take screen shot from different Screen shot app for the same screen